# How do I find the join command for kubeadm on the master?

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm

I've lost the original 'kubeadm join' command when I previously ran `kubeadm init`.

How can I retrieve this value again?

Answer (score 211, accepted):

```
kubeadm token create --print-join-command
```

Comment: I can get the token but it prints a warning. Is it possible to only print the token? without any warning, just the token itself?

Comment: Possibly the error goes to stderr. You could try `2> /dev/null`.

Comment: wow! you are just awesome. It is working, but i am not sure if this will guarantee it is working everytime?

Comment: I love you!! ❤️

Answer (score 35):

To print a `join` command for a *new worker node* use:

- `kubeadm token create --print-join-command`

But if you need to join a *new control plane node*, you need to recreate a new key for the control plane `join` command. This can be done with three simple steps:

1. Re upload certificates in the already working master node with `kubeadm init phase upload-certs --upload-certs`. That will generate a new certificate key.
2. Print `join` command in the already working master node with `kubeadm token create --print-join-command`.
3. Join a new control plane node with `$JOIN_COMMAND_FROM_STEP2 --control-plane --certificate-key $KEY_FROM_STEP1`.

This might not work for the old Kubernetes versions but I tried with the new version and it worked for me.

Comment: This is such an awesome and elegant solution. Thank you it works flawlessly.

Answer (score 17):

To create `kubeadm join` command, please run the following commands:

**Step 1 - Retrieve Token CA Hash:**

```sh
openssl x509 -pubkey -in /etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt \
    | openssl rsa -pubin -outform der 2>/dev/null \
    | openssl dgst -sha256 -hex \
    | sed 's/^.* //'
```

This command will provide you public key.

**Step 2 - Retrieve bootstrap Tokens:**

```sh
kubeadm token list
```

This will print all tokens, so copy the token value under `TOKEN` with the  description "The default bootstrap token generated by `kubeadm init`."

**Step 3 - Creates `kubeadm init` command:**

Now use following syntax to create `join` command without creating a new token:

```
kubeadm join <ip-address>:6443\
    --token=<token-from-step-2> \
    --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:<ca-hash-from-step-1>
```

`kubeadm token create` command creates a new token, in this case without any description, so for you not to create any additional tokens, just pick the token which has a `DESCRIPTION` as mentioned in ***Step 2***.

Comment: Got this error in Step1:



sed: -e expression #1, char 9: unknown option to `s'

Comment: trailing couple of ** has to be removed from the command then it will work

Answer (score 5):

Run the below command on your master node machine.

```
kubeadm token create --print-join-command
```

This command will generate the new token as well as the join command which you can use at your worker node to join the cluster.

Answer (score 3):

If you are joining control plane nodes, you will need a certificate key in the command too:

```
kubeadm token create \
--print-join-command \
--certificate-key \
$(kubeadm alpha certs certificate-key)
```

The `kubeadm alpha certs certificate-key` command will generate a new certificate key on demand as per the documentation [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/kubeadm-init/#uploading-control-plane-certificates-to-the-cluster)

To Join a worker node, the command `kubeadm token create --print-join-command` given in the accepted answer is sufficient

Comment: In the newer Kubernetes versions the certificate key command is without `alpha` - `kubeadm certs certificate-key`

Answer (score 2):

Building off @Abhishek Jain's answer, here's a script to print the `kubeadm join` command with a little help from `jq`:

```sh
# get the join command from the kube master
CERT_HASH=$(openssl x509 -pubkey -in /etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt \
| openssl rsa -pubin -outform der 2>/dev/null \
| openssl dgst -sha256 -hex \
| sed 's/^.* //')
TOKEN=$(kubeadm token list -o json | jq -r '.token' | head -1)
IP=$(kubectl get nodes -lnode-role.kubernetes.io/master -o json \
| jq -r '.items[0].status.addresses[] | select(.type=="InternalIP") | .address')
PORT=6443
echo "sudo kubeadm join $IP:$PORT \
--token=$TOKEN --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:$CERT_HASH"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bash script that automate this task

```
read -p 'master ip address : ' ipaddr
sha_token = "$(openssl x509 -pubkey -in /etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt | openssl rsa -pubin -outform der 2>/dev/null | openssl dgst -sha256 -hex | sed 's/^.* //')"
token = "$(kubeadm token list | awk '{print $1}' | sed -n '2 p')"
echo "kubeadm join $ipaddr:6443 --token=$token --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:$sha_token"
```